# Regular expression: Find numbers beginning and ending with different digits

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression that can be used to find numbers that begin and end with different digits.

I tried with the following: `^(\d)\d*(?!\1)$`

However, this does not work, it gives positive matches for numbers like

1. 121
2. 1233
3. 1441

Where am I getting it wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: your file has 1. 121 or just 121 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex doesn't actually *match* the last digit. You should do:

```
^(\d)\d*(?!\1)\d$
              ^^
              match the last digit!
```

Your regex just asserts that there isn't the starting digit at the end. Well, an empty string is also "not the starting digit", so it matches things like `1221`. You have to tell it to match "a **digit** that is not the starting digit".

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o3Xyy7/1)

Comment: `^(\d)\d*(?!\1)\d$` also excludes a single digit.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Exactly! Single digits start and end with the same digit, so shouldn't be matched.

Comment: Yeah :) Just not sure whether OP wants to match them or exclude them. Since there is no example for that.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the positive lookahead `(?!\d*\1$)` after the capturing group to assert that what follows is not zero or more times a digit ending with group 1:

[`^(\d)(?!\d*\1$)\d*$`](https://regex101.com/r/0xdLxV/1)

Comment: @Jyotirmoy if single digits should not be matched because they start and end with the same digit, change last quantifier `*` to `+` [`^(\d)(?!.*\1$)\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/odLsJj/1)